# Why does YOLO add 'background' class to the object detection even when we have not added that class? How to remove it?

Tags: annotations, object-detection, yolo, yolov8

Why does YOLO add 'background' class to the object detection even when we have not added that class? How to remove it?

I am trying to train YOLO v8x model on custom data. In the confusion matrix I saw that background class has been added which I haven't annotated. Later I observed this happening with YOLO v5 as well. If anyone has any idea on this , could you please tell me?
Also, how to remove this class?
and where can we check which all classes are considered in the model for training?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the model's classes list by calling `model.names`.
It will not contain the 'background' class because this is the default concept defining false-positive predictions of your model when it sees non-existing objects in the background. No need to try to remove it. It is useful to show it in a confusion matrix, so you can estimate the model performance relative to if it tends to generate false-positive predictions and which of your classes are subject to this mistake.